# Open an File in Java with O_NONBLOCK

Tags: java, unix, nonblocking, mkfifo

Given a pair of named pipes (FIFOs, one for reading, one for writing) which are used to communicate with another process,
I want to **open both pipes in a way that is interruptible**.

I have tested `Files.newInputStream()`, `Files.newByteChannel()` and `new RandomAccessFile()`.
The problem I get is that when I open the pipes read-only (resp. write-only), the `open()` call will block, and thus the thread doing `Files.newInputStream()` etc will block until the other process has opened its end of the pipe.

This means that it is impossible for me to interrupt the opening process, e.g. when I decide to shut down a module or connect to a different set of pipes. That close() call will have to wait for the pipe to be open.

A workaround I have found is to use modes `rw` (or `StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE`) to open my files. This makes sure that there is somebody opening "the other end" (myself), so that `open()` does not block, but `read()` blocks as expected.

However, that breaks the ability to detect the other process closing the pipe. Normally, I would get a `Broken Pipe` exception on the writing end, and an EOF / `ClosedByInterruptException` on the other end. This happens only when I'm the last reader/writer on the pipe, which will never happen if I have both pipes open R+W.
Thread.interrupt() will interrupt a NIO read (f.ex. stream.getChannel().read(x), but not an open().

Now: **Is there a possibility of getting a `ByteChannel` or `InputStream` from an `open(O_NONBLOCK)` call in Java?**

All call paths I have found and traced give no possibility of passing that flag. [open(3p)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open.3p.html) tells me that this would return successfully for reading (and hopefully block on the `read()`), and the writing end will error ENXIO, so that I can retry in a bit (but still have a chance to interrupt my retries if I choose).

Even `AsynchronousFileChannel` seems to call `open()` before opening its thread pool, so that would have the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you use a blocking operation in a separate thread? You could then wrap your read operation into a function that checks if the open operation is finished.

Comment: I do, but then I can't ever close the pipe (while it's blocked) -- which locks up a thread each time I want to change the file. Also, I can't close synchronously.

Comment: Check if you can use `Thread.interrupt()` to get the thread out of the blocked `Files.newInputStream()`. If the function is interruptible this should result in an `InterrupdedException`.

Comment: Already did. Thread.interrupt() can interrupt a NIO read (f.ex. `stream.getChannel().read(x)`, but not an `open()`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answeting in comments only.

Comment: Edited my question to include that :)